# autowire give null calling in webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, dependency-injection

I use spring dependency injection, I have following classes, in my project 
- UserService/UserServiceImpl
- RequestHandler

I send Webservice request to RequestHandler class and invoke, createPostRequest() method, but every time the out put is -> Say Null

```
@controller("handler")
@Path("/UserManagement")
public class RequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @PermitAll
    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    public String createPostRequest() {
        if(service == null) {
            System.out.println("Say Null");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Null");
            service.printName();
        }
        return "success";
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface UserService {

    void saveUser(final String username);
}
```

---

```
@Service("service")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    public void printName(){
      System.out.println("user serviceImpl exec");
    }
}
```

---

```
application-context.xml

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxx.xxx" />
```

is there to scan dependencies.

If i use to check it in a another main method in following way, It will work fine. output -> user serviceImpl exec

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("core-context.xml");      

        final RequestHandler userService = context.getBean("handler", RequestHandler.class);
        userService.createPostRequest();
    }
```

---

Any way I calling to the method createPostRequest() in RequestHandler class through the web service - localhost:8080/Test/UserManagement/save
it execute and say the **service** object is null. 
and give the output-> Say Null

I want to execute the method through a web service. My way I use to call through web service is wrong or what i missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `createPostRequest()` is a controller method that will server web requests to the url `/save`.  You cannot directly invoke this function from Java. To invoke this method, you should try to navigate to `<url to your web app>/save' in a web browser.

Comment: Method invoked through, 
localhost:8080/Test/UserManagement/save

problem is in service object not autowired.and staying as null

Comment: just to clarify, does that solve your question or is there something else you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, not solved. 
 @Autowired
    private UserService service;

not meant to null

Comment: can you try `context.getBean(RequestHandler.class)`

Comment: Your JAX-RS and Spring integration is incorrect.

Comment: what's wrong there? it execute the public String **createPostRequest()** method.                                                                                                                                      
want to no why it is not working **@autowird**

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with:

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
```

instead of

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

i think spring servlet can set the spring annotated propperties. it's a theory.